# How to display a background image in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a background image in a `<section>` in my html using css. I am hosting locally using XAMPP and the URL is coming from my Imgur account. When I run my code, the background image does not appear. Any ideas why the image won't show?

```css
.bigslide {
  background-image: url("https://imgur.com/haukzXN");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page1">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page3">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="start">
    <h1>DT Professional Carpet Cleaning and Hanyman Service.</h1>
    <section class="bigslide">
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: you need to give the `bigslide` some height.

Comment: Adding a height and width didnt fix your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong link from the https://imgur.com site. The link you used it not the link of the image but the link to view the image online.

Use this one instead;

```css
.bigslide {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/haukzXN.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bigslide">
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your link is to the imgur web page; this is the link to your image:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKc3s.jpg

So just change your CSS class like this:

```
.bigslide {
  background-image: url("https://imgur.com/haukzXN.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}
```